# Render an image in twig from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, twig

I stored image files via GridFS, is it possible to render those images in twig? For now I can render it within a controller by setting the header content-type and content in Response object but how can I do it when rendering a list of documents with images stored from MongoDB in twig?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

What I did after searching was returning

```
"data:".$this->getMimeType().";base64," . base64_encode($this->file->getMongoGridFSFile()->getBytes())
```

in src attribute of an image tag.

I'm not sure if it has any drawback and if it can be cached, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to serve the images directly to users via http (using nginx-gridfs, for example) and just place ing src links.